# How can I retrieve values from the uri in express js?

Tags: node.js, uri, express

Hello I want to retrieve a value from the uri and use it in my code, for example what would you do if you had something like http://mysite.com/uri1/uri2 and you wanted to get only uri2 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
app.get("/:uri/:id", function(req, res) {
    var uri = req.params.uri,
        id = req.params.id;

    // do code
});
```

To clarify `:uri` and `:id` are named url segments.

The following with also work

```
app.get("/rooms/:roomId", function(req, res) {
    Rooms.get(req.params.roomId, function(err, rooms) {
        res.render("rooms/index", { rooms: rooms });
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry but I can't understand how does :uri or :id are regular expressions, what if I had another(common) regular expression or just a string?

Comment: @rabidmachine you should read the express docs ;) or read the express examples

Comment: thanks anyway the reason I'm confused is because you are using the same name in the uri and the req that makes it look not so portable to me... could you for example do something like app.get("/:user(some_name)"... and when I would call user I get some_name ?